# uploading xml file to sql, turn off primary key in command

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I've searched google and youtube and here of course and i can't find the answer. I need to turn the identity insert On and OFF but don't know how to do that in the sql command of the ADO.Net project. I'm sure it must be extremely easy for you highly experienced people.

additional information I'm using c#, visual studio and sql server, i don't know if that helps narrow the problem down?

here is sql command i tried in the ado.net project.

```
sql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT HomeCareVisit ON insert into HomeCareVisit values(" 
       + VisitRefNo + ",'" + PatientNo + "','" + ScheduledDateTime + "','" 
       + TreatmentInstructions + "','" + MedicalStaffID + "','" + Priority + "','" 
       + ActualVisitDateTime + "','" + TreatmentProvided + "','" + Prescription 
       + "','" + AdvisoryNotes + "'," + (FurtherVisitRequired ? "1" : "0") + " );";
```

and it gave the error

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_VisitRefNo'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.HomeCareVisit'.
The statement has been terminated.

here is the code shows what data type the column are

```
VisitRefNo = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
PatientNo = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
ScheduledDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
TreatmentInstructions = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString();
MedicalStaffID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[4]);
Priority = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString();
ActualVisitDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[6]);
TreatmentProvided = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[7].ToString();
Prescription = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[8].ToString();
AdvisoryNotes = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[9].ToString();
FurtherVisitRequired = Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[10]);
```

Comment: You should learn how to use **parametrized queries** to avoid (a) negative performance and (b) SQL injection attacks ....

Comment: I will do that after the 5th.

Comment: As the error says you can't use the string representation of the bool `False`. If it's a bit you should be able to use `(FurtherVisitRequired ? "1" : "0")` to make it work, but as marc_s says parameters...

Comment: @Don
where do i insert the "(FurtherVisitRequired ? "1" : "0")"? is that into the command line or the convert?

Comment: replace `" + FurtherVisitRequired + "` with `" + (FurtherVisitRequired ? "1" : "0") + "`

Comment: @Don
thanks. that fix that exception. but now it's saying "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_VisitRefNo'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.HomeCareVisit'.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: That's because you're insert same values in first column, so SQL primary key constraint doesn't allow duplicate.

Comment: @veljasije 
Then how does one upload data to xml change it offline and then upload the data back to the sql when they have internet connection again?

Comment: Create some table without primery key on `VisitNo` column, insert data in that table and check whether it has duplicates, and which they are. Clear that data, and then import in main table

Comment: `UPDATE`, `MERGE`, `TRUNCATE TABLE`, `IF EXISTS ()`, `IF NOT EXISTS ()` there are different options depending on version/data/expected behavior.

Comment: thank you everyone. If my reputation were 15 I'd be voting all your answers up. woot ya. got it working. :))

Answer (score 1):

This is the [command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) to do it

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable ON
```

Comment: No. that doesn't work I changed the command to sql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT HomeCareVisit ON insert into HomeCareVisit values(" + VisitRefNo + ",'" + PatientNo + "','" + ScheduledDateTime + "','" + TreatmentInstructions + "','" + MedicalStaffID + "','" + Priority + "','" + ActualVisitDateTime + "','" + TreatmentProvided + "','" + Prescription + "','" + AdvisoryNotes + "'," + FurtherVisitRequired + " );"; got "Invalid column name 'False'.
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'HomeCareVisit' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON."

Comment: can you place a profiler to catch the call that is sent to the db?

Comment: i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT HomeCareVisit ON insert into HomeCareVisit(column_names) values(" 
       + VisitRefNo + ",'" + PatientNo + "','" + ScheduledDateTime + "','" 
       + TreatmentInstructions + "','" + MedicalStaffID + "','" + Priority + "','" 
       + ActualVisitDateTime + "','" + TreatmentProvided + "','" + Prescription 
       + "','" + AdvisoryNotes + "'," + FurtherVisitRequired + " );";
```

where `column_names` is list of table columns in order in which you insert.

I think you pass string in place where table doesn't expect this, like TreatmentProvided column (by name, i assume that you pass True/False, but not as string).

Comment: @vlejasije It's returning the error "Invalid column name 'False'." I copy and pasted the column names so i know they are all spelled correctly.

Comment: Which columns accepts True/False values? TreatmentsProvided? FurtherVisitRequired?

Comment: it's FurtherVisitRequired that is bool

Comment: include still this line at the end, I don't know can this be the problem: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT HomeCareVisit OFF`